# Getting TypeError: 'range' object is not callable when trying to get the sum of the squares of odd numbers between 1 and 1000

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the sum of the squares of odd numbers between 1 and 1000, but for some reason I'm getting the error `"TypeError: 'range' object is not callable"` What could the issue be?

```
squares = []

oddnumbers = range(1,1001,2)

for number in oddnumbers:

    squares.append(number**2)

mysum = oddnumbers (squares)

print("sum of squares of odd integers between 1 and 1000 is ", mysum)
```

Comment: `oddnumbers (squares)` is the same as `range(1, 1001, 2)(squares)`. I think you want `mysum = sum(squares)`?

Comment: For future use: `print(f'sum of squares of odd integers between 1 and 1000 is {sum(i**2 for i in range(1, 1001, 2))}')`

Answer (score 0):

Use keyword `sum`

Try:

```
squares = []
oddnumbers = range(1,1001,2)
for number in oddnumbers:
    squares.append(number**2)
mysum = sum(squares)

print("sum of squares of odd integers between 1 and 1000 is ", mysum)
```